# Make an empty <div> collapse, with a width and margin

Tags: html, css

I consider myself a beginner at HTML, so sorry if this is a no-brainer.

In the following example I'd like the 'LEFT' DIV to collapse when it is empty. However with BOTH the 'width' AND the 'margin' present it will not collapse. If I remove either one from the style it collapses fine.

```
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div style="float:left; width:25%; margin:40px 0 40px 0" >
        LEFT
      </div>
      <div style="float:left; margin:40px 0 40px 0">
        RIGHT
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea how I can make the "LEFT" DIV collapse if I remove the word "LEFT"?

Thanks

-John

Comment: Are you using jQuery to remove the word Left?

Comment: use only margin: 40px 0; instead margin: 40px 0 40px 0;  ||||| That's not a solution also. Just an advice.

Comment: just google `collapse empty div`.. and booom!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `:empty` pseudo class. but it will mean really empty, even white-space **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/joy08408/)**

empty like this :

```
<div></div>
```

or

```
<div<!-- whatever --></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the empty selector

```
div:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

this needs to be put either on an external css or in an `<style>` tag

Also `margin:40px 0 40px 0;` and `margin:40px 0;` are the same

Answer (score 1):

Css : checking if a div is empty :

```
#left:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/60ycunra/2/)

or You can use jquery to handle this checking with  more flexiblity :
for example more usable if you want to check even the div is empty or have `LEFT` or some other specific content

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var leftcol = $("#left").html();
    alert (leftcol);
    if (leftcol == "LEFT" || leftcol == "") {
         $('#left').html('');
         $('#left').animate({ width: '0px'},'1000');        
        alert(' Left Div is empty !');
    } else {
        alert("Left Div is not empty");       
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/60ycunra/1/)

Comment: While true, I don't see the jQuery tag on the question.

Comment: oh, I missed that. I've updated my answer. Thanx for your attendance